# Cannot see Firebase upload mapping file task

Tags: android, gradle, firebase, gradlew, firebase-crash-reporting

Uploading mapping file with command:

`./gradlew -PFirebaseServiceAccountFilePath=<path> \
:app:firebaseUploadFreeReleaseProguardMapping`

Runs successfully but i cannot see any tasks starting with`firebaseUpload` in my `app:tasks`. Do somebody know why?

Comment: What version of gradle are you using?

Comment: Are you using the Beta build of Android Studio? It worked for me already, but now with Android Studio 2.3 Beta 2 and this gradle plugin "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0-beta2" it doesn't work anymore...

Comment: I also get this error when calling "./gradlew :clean": Cannot create tasks to upload Proguard Mapping File.java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 3):

We also have encountered this problem. 
Solution is to add `minifyEnabled` in your apps `build.gradle` like so:

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
    ...
    minifyEnabled true
    ...
    }
 }
```

And sync your project, then you will have those tasks created.

Answer (score 2):

@MatBos thanks for the hint. This didn't solve the problem for me.

But I had this cause:

```
buildTypes {
  debug {
    minifyEnabled true
    useProguard false
  }
}
```

When I change *minifyEnabled* to **false** it is working again!

Disabling proguard in debug mode, disabled also the firebase tasks for the production code...

Comment: Thank you! It it created "firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping" task for me when i disabled useProguard to debug build type.

Comment: I just got hit by this. And I reported it Firebase team.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload mapping files manually too. 
Go to destination.

**app/build/outputs/mapping/debug/mapping.txt**

And then upload it.